# How to select first list box item by default?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox

I'm using `ObservableCollection` to bind data into list box. Is there a way to make first list item to be selected right after data binding? Is there any event I can use ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after (or any point after) setting the datacontext for the listbox (or parent object - probably the page), just set the selected index to the first item in the list.

```
listbox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

If you've got a handler for when the selected index is changed then be sure to ignore when you first set the index.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property named `IsSelected` in the object contained within the `ObservableCollection`. Bind this to the `ListBoxItem`'s `IsSelected` property via a `TwoWay` binding.

Then, in the page's `OnLoaded` callback (or wherever you're binding the collection to the `ListBox`), do something like this

```
foreach( var obj in myCollection ) {
  obj.IsSelected = false;
}
if( myCollection.Count > 0 ) {
  myCollection[0].IsSelected = true;
}
// bind the collection to the listbox
```

Answer (score 0):

why won't you try something like

```
var listBoxItem = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myList.First());
listBoxItem.Focus();
```

or

```
listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
```

Comment: When should I do that? I have to use specific event to ensure that all data has been loaded ?

Comment: yes, whenever your data is bounded and you're sure that ListBox has some items, you're allowed to do so... otherway 'listBoxItem' will be null